# Old Hangul (옛한글) on Safari not rendering

Tags: macos, unicode, safari

I have a Mac(MacOS 12.0.1) and use Safari as my default browser. Across my Mac, despite having several fonts that support it, Old Hangul (옛한글) does not render how it is supposed to.

In more detail, Hangul—the Korean script—is mainly encoded into Unicode by means of encoding every possible block, i.e. 한 and 글 are their own glyphs along with 하 and 그, ㅎ and ㄱ, ㅡ and ㅏ, &c. But when Old Hangul was encoded, a new encoding method was used so that only the letters need to be encoded and the computer will render them together correctly using the appropriate fonts, e.g. ㅎㅏㄴㄱㅡㄹ will render as 한글. However, despite having several fonts installed in FontBook, Old Hangul refuses to render machine wide, save for word processors when the appropriate font is applied. For example, the ᄀᆞᇫ다 entry on wiktionary([https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ᄀᆞᇫ다](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%84%80%E1%86%9E%E1%87%AB%EB%8B%A4)) just appears as a string of letters with 다 next to it. But, when I past that text into Pages and apply a font that supports Old Hangul, it renders fine. How can I fix this for Safari and or my entire computer so that 옛한글 renders correctly?

Comment: As far as I can tell [I don't speak Korean] Old Hangul is not a standard macOS font substitution. When I look at that page, I'm seeing Apple Myungjo & Ariel Unicode MS

Comment: Something to do with Unicode Normalization - `옛` (U+C61B,  *Hangul Syllable Ieung Ye Sios*)
- `한` (U+D55C,  *Hangul Syllable Hieuh A Nieun*)
- `글` (U+AE00,  *Hangul Syllable Kiyeok Eu Rieul*), i.e `옛한글` decomposition is 
- `ᄋ` (U+110B,  *Hangul Choseong Ieung*)
- `ᅨ` (U+1168,  *Hangul Jungseong Ye*)
- `ᆺ` (U+11BA,  *Hangul Jongseong Sios*)
- `ᄒ` (U+1112,  *Hangul Choseong Hieuh*)
- `ᅡ` (U+1161,  *Hangul Jungseong A*)
- `ᆫ` (U+11AB,  *Hangul Jongseong Nieun*)
- `ᄀ` (U+1100,  *Hangul Choseong Kiyeok*)
- `ᅳ` (U+1173,  *Hangul Jungseong Eu*)
- `ᆯ` (U+11AF,  *Hangul Jongseong Rieul*)

Comment: See [UAX #15: Unicode Normalization Forms](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/).

Comment: Thanks JosefZ, this does seem to be the issue, the text '옛한글' renders fine for me because it uses the old encoding method of having every combination of letters already rendered. However, the text 'ᄀᆞᇫ다' does not render correctly. It appears as three separate letters (like this: ㄱㆍㅿ) followed by '다' which is encoded using the old method mentioned previously. How can I get correct Unicode Normalisation working on my machine?